# How to tell android to NEVER modify a specify view

Tags: android, view

I'm creating my tablelayout by code, because i get values from db, included column names. I want to tell android it can't never ever modify row of column names once i've added it at my tablelayout. Can I  do it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Can you explain what you mean by "modify" and maybe provide some drawings/screenshots to elaborate?

Comment: What makes you think you need to create the TableLayout in your code? You can have a TableLayout in your xml layout file, than add columns and rows from your code. You can create a header row with column names, but to the app, that row would still be data that your app fills.

Comment: i've not explained it good. I've create tablelayout in xml and row by code. I want when I add this column it can't be modify in any way. Every modify you can think

Comment: Sorry, I'm italian and my english is really bad